# В чём разница типов объявления массива в JavaScript?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Бодрого всем здравия!
Вопрос может быть и примитивный, но всё же.
Вопрос следующий. В чём разница объявления массива?
Первый случай:

```
var months = new Array()
 months[0] = "Янв";
 months[1] = "Фев";
 months[2] = "Мар";
 months[3] = "Апр";
 months[4] = "Май";
 months[5] = "Июн";
 months[6] = "Июл";
 months[7] = "Авг";
 months[8] = "Сен";
 months[9] = "Окт";
 months[10] = "Ноя";
 months[11] = "Дек";
```

Второй случай:

```
var months = ["Янв", "Фев", "Мар", "Апр", "Май", "Июн", "Июл", "Авг", "Сен", "Окт", "Ноя", "Дек"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ни в чем.
Итог один и тот же. 1вый вариант, чаще всего используется для того, что бы в ходе работы с кодом заменять уже готовое значение массива или дополнить его ключом не по очереди.
А второй, более удобно и просто запихнуть большое количество данных в массив

Comment: Дополню вас: Первый вариант - динамический массив. Второй вариант - статический или же как константа, вы заранее объявляете массив и используете его. Компилятор же невидимо создает массив: a = newдлArray() и заполняет его а затем передаёт вам, для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: @Человек_Борща в js отсутствуют статические массивы. Разница лишь в размере массива - `new Array()` создает новый _пустой_ массив, в который уже помещаются объекты. Во втором случае массив заполняется сразу, то есть по сути сокращает и код и количество запускаемых инструкции, и ,вероятно, количество используемой памяти

Comment: @Человек_Борща вы какую-то ерунду говорите, если считаете что это не так, пожалуйста приведите ссылку на описание "статических массивов" в стандарте языка. И про "компилятор" поподробнее. А так-же объясните как идея чего-то статического или констант клеится с такой вот конструкцией:

    var b=[1,2,3,c]